# Private User folders by default using file permissions on Windows 10 system

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, file-permissions, administrator

There are many ways one can change Permissions for certain files and folders on Windows manually (e.g. through Properties > Security > Permissions). But how do I change the default Permissions to make that for any just created new user on the system his user folder (with Documents, etc.) will be private, meaning only said user and system administrators will have full permissions, but other regular users wouldn't?

Comment: Have you tried to modify the default user profile `C:\Users\Default`? Note this is a hidden folder, hence you have to activate the settings in Explorer to show hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

The only permissions on a new user profile (`C:\Users\username`) are for access
by that user account, the administrators and the system.
No other user can access such a private user profile, but there is no way to block
an administrator from fully accessing it.

For sharing files with other users, use the `C:\Users\Public` folder.
All local users can access this "profile", but cannot access your private user profile.

Comment: What about personal folders with changed locations? For example, `user 1` has his `Documents` moved to `D:\Users\User1\Documents`, and I want to apply similar location pattern for every new user, all private permissions included.

Comment: Changed locations don't imply automatic changed permissions. If a user remapped his folders, it's up to him to set the permissions as he wants.